# Repository pattern with entity versioning / event sourcing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, repository

I am new to `ASP.Net` and `Repository Pattern`. What I am trying to do is implement versioning in every data change in `Entity` in `Repository Pattern`. I know I should have used `CQRS` and event sourcing but here the project is huge and change of Architecture is not allowed. So it would be great If any one can help me.
I tried binding data in requestmodel like this:

```
 public static RequestModel<T> ToRequestModel<T>(this T model) 
{
 var requestModel = new RequestModel<T>()
   { Model = model, 
     IpAddress = ClientIP, 
     UserData = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserData(),
     Url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.PathAndQuery,
      LogDate = DateTime.Now
   }; 
    return requestModel; 
}

   public void ExampleFunction(RequestModel<EntityViewModel> request)
        {
            using (_unitOfWork)
            {
              _modelService.add(request.Model);
              _requestService.add(request);
               unitOfWork.commit();
            }
        }
```

and tried to save it with every entity service but i find out if error occur in saving Requestmodel it also wont allow to save that entity data so i have to make it independent
 Thank you in advance.

Comment: I tried binding data in requestmodel like this 
 `public static RequestModel<T> ToRequestModel<T>(this T model)
        {
            var requestModel = new RequestModel<T>()
            {
                Model = model,
                IpAddress = ClientIP,
                UserData = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserData(),
                Url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.PathAndQuery,
                LogDate = DateTime.Now

            };
            return requestModel;
        }`

Comment: and tried to save it with every entity service but i find out if error occur in saving Requestmodel it also wont allow to save that entity data so i have to make it independent. @JohnB

Comment: please edit your original post with the code - code in comments is very hard to read...

Comment: @JohnB done brother.

Comment: is this using EF Core?

Comment: check this out: https://entityframework-plus.net/audit

Comment: @JohnB this is asp.net mvc brother

Comment: ok, so you don't use some sort of ORM like Entity Framework?

Comment: @JohnB Yes bro i am using EF

Comment: then i don't understand your `this is asp.net mv` comment.  good luck!